# How to make dynamic import/require depend of variable with code cleanup?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, create-react-app

I have react app created by "react-create-app" with latest react 16.12 and Webpack

I need to make import with dependence on variable, like it:

```js
    if (process.env.SOMEVAR === "a1") Routes = require("./xxx").default;
    if (process.env.SOMEVAR === "a2") Routes = require("./yyy").default;
    if (process.env.SOMEVAR === "a3") Routes = require("./zzz").default;
```

Run command: `set "SOMEVAR=a1" && npm run build`

This code will make `main.chunk.js` with this 3 modules `xxx`/`yyy`/`zzz` inside, without dependency of `SOMEVAR`

I've accidentally discovered that when I use `NODE_ENV` variable name - **it works like I need**! Example:

```js
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") Routes = require("./xxx").default;
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") Routes = require("./yyy").default;
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "test") Routes = require("./zzz").default;
```

Run command: `set "NODE_ENV=production" && npm run build`

This code will make `main.chunk.js` **with only xxx module inside**!

**Question:** How to make any other variables with same effect instead of `NODE_ENV` (I need to have inside of build only modules which uses after my `if`)? How it works? I cant find any info about this effect in "WebPack docs".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the provided example i think this is not the best approach.

You can define a dynamic pluggin in that exposes a custom global variable to the build.
Adding to your webpack plugins config something like :

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    EnabledRoutes: {
        testing: true,
        production: true,
        development: true
    }
})
```

And this way you can use process environment or reading a build config like this:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    EnabledRoutes: {
        testing: process.env.ROUTES_TESTING,
        production: Config.routes.production,
        development: true
    }
})
```

And in the client router directly you can check to add the additional routes:

```
if(EnabledRoutes.testing)
{
    APPEND routes.
}
```

or

```
if (EnabledRoutes.testing) Routes = require("./xxx").default;
```